# how to debug the Application over WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, adb

I want to debug my application over WiFi, I know this commands "Run adb tcpip 5555." etc. , but where do I have to write this command in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Type in the Terminal at the bottom of Android Studio.Maybe you should install a wifiadb app on mobile.